# Flyway usage with ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite, flyway

The database migration mechanism by `SQLiteHelper` methods `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` is not convenient to me. So I decided to use **Flyway** tool which is compatible with android. It is written in flyway documentation that you should init/migrate database in main activity. To extent this I have couple questions. Is it right place to init/migrate database in main activity when application uses ORMLite. If not, where I should place the flyway migration method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Place it at the very beginning of the main activity. It needs to run early, as the rest of the code depends on the migrated structure.

Comment: I think that to place migration/init code in main activity is not right place because it is possible that application has been installed for the first time and due to that, in that particular moment, database is not created by Android OS at all. For that reason, if there is any script which tries to modify any table will fail. I am wondering why not to place migration code in `SQLiteOpenHelper` class in `onUpgrade` method and init code in `onCreate` method because these methods will be called by android OS on database initialization and upgrade.

Comment: OK. `SQLiteOpenHelper` isn't right place to hold flyway migration code too because `SQLiteDabatase` object is thread-safe and you cannot access it while `SQLiteOpenHelper` operates. I have to take back my words. Main activity is right place for migration but with one condition. The very first script has to be schema population script. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. The first script creates the initial structure.